# Неправильно отображаются русские буквы

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, eclipse

Всем привет, у меня проблема.

Я работаю с vkapi через Java на Eclipse. Моя программа получает отправленные сообщения, исходящие игнорирует, а входящие обрабатывает и выводит в окно. В самой IDE с UTF-8 русские буквы отображаются правильно, а в экспортированном .jar уже не очень. Кто-нибудь в курсе, в чем проблема?

Объясните, пожалуйста, желательно поподробней.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте запустить jar с флагом -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: @Виктор работает, спасибо большое)